# Public folder permission in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails project, I noticed that when I put some files into my `public` folder, such as `.html, .pdf, .jpg`, they can be opened via a browser. But when I put other files, such as `.txt` or files with no file type, permission is denied.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /blog/public/test.txt on this server.
```

Where is this permission controlled?

Actually, it's interesting that the file `robots.txt`, which came automatically when the Rails project was set up, **can** be accessed! But `test.txt`, which I created, cannot be accessed.

Comment: @ShadyKiller I'm using a Scripts service from my school, and I actually don't know the answer to your question.

Comment: Show the error you are getting.  What is the web server you are using?

Comment: Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: check blog and public folder permissions

Comment: If you on some flavour of linux then  ls -la command is your friend. If your files permissions/user are different from the files that are being served, theres your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restart the server and see if it works. It usually works in rails 3 like breeze, but you might be on an older version of rails.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the asset pipeline which allows the html, css and js files only...